# What's the impact of using different file extensions on a webpage?

Tags: php, html

Hi I was just wondering if there is any way that using a .php file extension over a .html extension impacts on the site performance, how the server handles it, etc.

I'm asking this because I want to include the layout and footer that's on every page on my site using phps include. However this means making every page on the site have a .php extension, so is this bad in anyway or does it not matter?

Thanks

Comment: see sidebar to the right for topics on the same question.

Comment: It takes slightly longer for a web-server to *serve* a request for *dynamic content* then it does for *static content* as it's not just a literal byte-copy with the former. While the extension is often used to make the distinction it is not exclusively so. (I think it looks prettier if the web-server/resource mapping hides the fact that a dynamic page is being served.) Is this "slightly longer" impacting performance? Doubtful, but try a performance analysis if there is a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension in and of itself is irrelevant. How it's processed server-side, which is usually, but not always, tied to an extension will have an affect. That said, PHP will tend to be a bit slower, not accounting for caching -- or assuming both static and dynamic pages are cached equally.

That said, leveraging a server-side scripting language like PHP is a widely-accepted way to accomplish what you need. The performance hit will be negligible, especially in comparison to the development time savings of maintaining N pages with identical content.

Answer (score 0):

AFIAK just some servers do it for security, nobody will know your programming language, so they can't try programming language specific attacks.

Also some hide server banner from Apache or other web server they are using, it will prevent hackers to know OS, web server and programming language.

Comment: OS and server fingerprinting is rather trivial. The order of response headers, network information, error messages, etc can give it away. Security through obscurity is rather pointless. I mean if OP doesn't change default session settings for PHP for example session ID will be PHPSESSID. Just saying.

Comment: Yes, but a server/site who considers hiding such basic information, should consider the rest, like changing PHP session ID, fingerprints in error pages (easy, with a .htaccess and redirecting ALL errors to homepage). It will stop MOST of security scanners.

Comment: You should not be worried about security scanners, but rather that those security scanners don't exploit a hole by instead focusing your energy and time on making secure code and keeping system up to date. Trying to hide your key under the doormat and hoping they don't find it is not as effective as having a bouncer at the door verifying if they are on guest list.

Comment: That's first step, without that you can't worry about server banner, I meant after securing everything, now it's to EVEN hide fingerprints. That's just a prestigious thing, high profile sites I've seen do it.

Comment: High profile sites do it...and many still end up getting hacked. Lesson learned: don't waste manpower and resources on hiding stuff, but rather fixing it and making it secure in the first place.

Comment: Yes, as I said just prestigious thing. Also there is so much high profiles sites hasn't been ever hacked. 100% of hacks occur because of human mistakes, wrong configs, not using a programming who knows security, etc.